# I Have Error a google map android api v2 is not loaded

Tags: java, android, xml, oop, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a project of google map android api v2 but i run this project in my phone a logcat has error

> **Falied to load map.Error contacting Google servers. This is probable an authentication issue(but could be due to network errors)**

so my code is Here

in class HomeActivity

```
package com.mpa.emvi;

import com.mpa.emvi.R;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is a Layout HomeActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendDS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/send_destination"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is a Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mpa.emvi"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.1.0">
    <permission
    android:name="com.mpa.emvi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.mpa.emvi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- External storage for caching. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- My Location -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
        <activity
            android:name="com.mpa.emvi.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My-Release-API-KEY"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

You see my code. What do you thing?
Ok I'm try to seach same issue in this and i try re-generate new api key but not work.
In my project aleady import a google service lib and android support v4.
In google console i open google map android api v2 service.
In google console android apps: my-SHA1-serials;com.mpa.emvi

OK a lasting I'm a newbie android programmer and sorry for my english is poor.

Thank for every Answer.

Comment: Check if you have enables google maps for android in the google api console

Comment: Yes,I already enables a google map android api v2.

Comment: check if you have referenced google play services library project properly in your map project.

Comment: Yes sure,I have Referenced it.I add a google play services lib in to my project and I'm add a android-support-v4.jar in java build parth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now my app is showing the map.I forget delete old apk file and re-install new apk file it work.Thank For Any Answer Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your Api key in Manifest File?

Comment: Ok now my app is showing the map.I forget delete old apk file and re-install new apk file it work.Thank For Any Answer Thank.